# How to get check box values on auto scroll down using ajax action link in MVC .NET ?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am using ajax link to scroll down on the click event.

In controller:

[HttpGet}

```
Public ActionResult Autoscroll () 
{ 
  queryresult = // db operation 
  return view(result) 
} 

Public ActionResult Autoscroll (string[] checkboxids)
{ 
  // save selected values to db. 
 Return view ()
}
```

In view

```
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Load  more re", "Autoscroll " "Search", null, new  AjaxOptions 
{  HttpMethod = "GET",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
UpdateTargetId = "searcharea",
```

})

But when I click on submit button only checkboxes which were loaded for last click are available in httpost, how can I program it neatly? I want to do same like email load and check box selection thing.